# my query doesn't want to show in my textboxes

Tags: c#, sql, database, database-connection

I made 2 queries the first one he keeps showing nicely ,, and the 2nd one which is pretty much the same he doesn't show .. i select from a combobox and he has to show the names in the textboxes, but he shows after showing the name 1 ime in the 2nd text box he shows the id the 2nd time, i dont know whats wrong

```
    private void comboBox3_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //1
            con.Open();
            cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT a.naam FROM [dbo].activiteiten_in_reserveringen air, [dbo].activiteiten a , [dbo].reserveringen r ,[dbo].klanten k WHERE a.id = air.activiteit_id AND air.reservering_id = r.id AND k.id = r.klant_id", con);
            SqlDataReader myReader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            string SUM;
            while (myReader.Read())
            {
                SUM = myReader.GetString(0);
                Console.WriteLine(SUM);
                tbbActiviteit.Text = SUM;

            }


            con.Close();
        //2
            con.Open();
            cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT k.naam FROM [dbo].activiteiten_in_reserveringen air, [dbo].activiteiten a , [dbo].reserveringen r ,[dbo].klanten k WHERE a.id = air.activiteit_id AND air.reservering_id = r.id AND k.id = r.klant_id", con);
            SqlDataReader myReadera = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            string SUM2;
            while (myReadera.Read())
            {
                SUM2 = myReadera.GetString(0);
                Console.WriteLine(SUM2);
                tbbNaam.Text = SUM2;
            }


            con.Close();

    }
```

Comment: question is not clear..can you show what is the output you are getting and what you want..

Comment: remove con.Close();
            con.Open(); that line of code

Comment: Why aren't you using any of the parameters supplied by the event? Why don't you use something like `SELECT a.naam as A, k.naam as K` instead of executing the same query with a different `SELECT` twice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are selecting `k.naam` in second query while this column is in table `[dbo].activiteiten` with alias `a` which you have selected in first query `a.naam`. So you need to select `a.naam` in second query or give the table `[dbo].activiteiten` alias k.

Second query should be like this

```
SELECT a.naam FROM [dbo].activiteiten_in_reserveringen air, [dbo].activiteiten a , [dbo].reserveringen r ,[dbo].klanten k WHERE a.id = air.activiteit_id AND air.reservering_id = r.id AND k.id = r.klant_id
```